# Getting location data from a remote device

Tags: android

There are lots of tutorials around for getting the location of a 
user’s device, I want to acquire this information from a driver’s device, as I am building an app
for a taxi company, and the idea is to pass this location data
to a customer app, so the customers can track the driver’s
location. 
How would I address this??

Comment: use real time database or socket to upload driver locations  so you can get locations real time using customer app.

Comment: The customer sits in the taxi and you want to pass location info of a gps device in the taxi to the customers? Dont they have a gps chip in their phones themself?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 option maybe more...

op1:
create background service and using location listener, in location change call a api and update driver last location, and customer app call api in background service using timer (ex: every 30seconds call driver last api)

op2:
create notification service, every time u want send push to driver, and in notif service when receive this type of notif, call an api and update last location
and in every last location update, send push to customer

this is my way : (im using audio and some thing else, remove any thing u wont

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
private DBHelper DBConnection;
private Context context;
public LocationManager locationManager;
public MyLocationListener listener;
public static boolean gpsEnable = true;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private int lastVolume;
private AudioManager audioManager;
private boolean sendingListInProgress = false;
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
//private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(); 

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
    DBConnection = new DBHelper(context);
    DBConnection.DBCreate(context);
    IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
    i.addAction("android.intent.action.update_map");
    //registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    try {
        FirebaseCrash.log("Activity created");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        int minDistance = 10;
        int time = 8000;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        else
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, minDistance, listener);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "N", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setSound(null, null);
            channel.setDescription(String.valueOf(getText(R.string.app_name2)));
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name2));
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_small);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 479, new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK), 0));

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForeground(13, builder.build());
        } else {
            notificationManager.notify(13, builder.build());
        }
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        lastVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.ERROR, TAG, "NPE caught");
        //FirebaseCrash.report(ex);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    if (Cache.getInt(Cache.status) == 1) {
        startService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class));
    } else {
        if (locationManager != null && listener != null)
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        listener = null;
        locationManager = null;
        if (notificationManager != null)
            notificationManager.cancel(13);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}

private void playAlarmSound() { //play alarm when gps turn off
    if (mediaPlayer != null)
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getAssets().openFd("analog_alarm.mp3");
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
    checkGPS();
}

private void checkSound() {
    if (gpsEnable || Cache.getInt(Cache.status) == 0) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, lastVolume, 0);
    } else {
        new Handler().postDelayed(this::checkSound, 1500);
        playAlarmSound();
    }
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(final Location locations) {
        if (locations.getLatitude() > 20 && locations.getLongitude() > 20) {
            App.lastLat = locations.getLatitude(); //save last location some where
            App.lastLng = locations.getLongitude();//save last location some where
            Cache.set(Cache.lat, locations.getLatitude());//save last location some where
            Cache.set(Cache.lng, locations.getLongitude());//save last location some where
        }
        SendLocation(locations, isNetworkEnable());//api call
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        gpsEnable = false;
        if (Cache.getInt(Cache.status) == 1) { // true means active
            DBConnection.saveReport(context, new OfficialDriverEvents(0));
            checkSound();
            checkGPS();
        }
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        gpsEnable = true;
        DBConnection.saveReport(context, new OfficialDriverEvents(1));
        checkSound();
        checkGPS();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}

private void reportChangeToServer(List<OfficialDriverEvents> list) {
    ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    Call<Integer> call = apiService.officialDriverEvents(list);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Integer> call, @NonNull Response<Integer> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200)
                try {
                    if (response.body() != null && response.body() == 1) {
                        DBHelper.database.execSQL("DELETE FROM 'event'");
                    }

                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Integer> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}

private void SendLocation(Location getLocation, boolean isNetworkEnable) {
    if (!gpsEnable) {
        checkGPS();
    }
    if (isNetworkEnable) {
        checkDatabaseReportList();
        if (!sendingListInProgress) {
            checkDatabaseLocationList();
        }
    }
    if (getLocation.getLatitude() > 20 && getLocation.getLongitude() > 20) {
        Locations location = new Locations();
        location.setStrIMEI(Cache.getString(Cache.imei));
        location.setStrUnitId(Cache.getString(Cache.id));
        location.setLat(getLocation.getLatitude());
        location.setLon(getLocation.getLongitude());
        location.setDistance(0);
        location.setLogDate(Time.getNowPersianDate());
        location.setLogTime(Time.getNowTime());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            location.setViSpeed(String.valueOf((int) (getLocation.getSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond() * 3.6)));
            location.setAccurecy(String.valueOf(getLocation.getVerticalAccuracyMeters()));
            location.setSteps(String.valueOf(getLocation.getBearingAccuracyDegrees()));
        } else {
            location.setViSpeed(String.valueOf((int) (getLocation.getSpeed() * 3.6)));
            location.setAccurecy(String.valueOf(getLocation.getAccuracy()));
            location.setSteps(String.valueOf(getLocation.getBearing()));
        }
        if (isNetworkEnable) {
            SendRequest(location);
        } else {
            DBConnection.saveData(context, location);//request failed save in db for send this later
        }
    }
}

private void checkDatabaseLocationList() {
    List<Locations> lstLocations = DBConnection.openData(context);
    if (lstLocations != null && lstLocations.size() > 0) {
        sendingListInProgress = true;
        SendRequestList(lstLocations);
    } else {
        sendingListInProgress = false;
    }
}

private void checkDatabaseReportList() { // send all failed requests
    List<OfficialDriverEvents> list = DBConnection.getReport(context);
    if (list != null && list.size() > 0)
        reportChangeToServer(list);
}

private void SendRequestList(List<Locations> lstLocations) {
    ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);

    Call<Integer> call = apiService.saveMobileMovementList(lstLocations);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Integer> call, @NonNull Response<Integer> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200 && response.body() != null && response.body() == 1) {
                try {
                    DBHelper.database.execSQL("DELETE FROM 'gps' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM 'gps' LIMIT 1000)");
                    Log.d("peyloc", "list removed");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("peyloc", "list 200 catch: " + e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> checkDatabaseLocationList(), 20000);
                    Log.d("peyloc", "finally check for offline list");
                }
            } else {
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> checkDatabaseLocationList(), 20000);
                sendingListInProgress = false;
                Log.d("peyloc", "list not 200");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Integer> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            sendingListInProgress = false;
            Log.d("peyloc", "list onFailure");
        }
    });
}

private void checkGPS() { //check gps
    if (!gpsEnable) {
        if (!TurnOnLocationActivity.isRun && !TripAcceptActivity.isRun && !HomeFragment.isRun && !com.rayanandisheh.peysepar.helper.Location.isShowing)
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, TurnOnLocationActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
//            checkSound();
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkEnable() { //check network
    NetworkInfo netInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

private void SendRequest(final Locations location) {
    ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    Call<Integer> call = apiService.saveMobileMovement(location);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Integer> call, @NonNull Response<Integer> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200 && response.body() != null && response.body() == 1)
                Log.d("peyloc", "200 ok");
            else {
                Log.d("peyloc", "200 not ok");
                DBConnection.saveData(context, location);//request failed save in db for send this later
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Integer> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.d("peyloc", "onFailure");
            DBConnection.saveData(context, location);//request failed save in db for send this later
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/realtime-asset-tracking/index.html?index=..%2F..index#1

Try to implement it with firebase. It is the best way to track people and have real time tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **fused location provider** and any **real-time database** for better reliability.

The **Fused Location provider** is a higher-level Google Play Services API that wraps the underlying location sensors like GPS. You can accomplish tasks like:
1. Register for location connection events 
2. Connect to the location sensor
3. Register for updates or accuracy changes
4. Get the last location
For even simpler location updates, check out this smart-location-lib locations API wrapper.

[Android official document](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current)

[Retrieving Location with LocationServices API elaborated](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API)

**Firebase Realtime Database**
Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database that supports multiple platforms Android, iOS and Web. All the data is stored in JSON format and any changes in data reflect immediately by performing sync across all the platforms & devices. This allows us to build more flexible realtime apps easily with minimal effort.

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)

for your reference please go through 
[Real-time Asset Tracking sample code labs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/realtime-asset-tracking/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6)